# 3D RGL Plot not showing in R

Tags: r, pca3d

I am plotting a 3 dimensional PCA plot with R package "pca3d". However, the plot is not popping up as it usually does with conventional 2d plots (e. g. plotted with ggplot, ggbiplot or also with the 2d function of pca3d, i. e. pca2d).

```
> library(pca3d)
> pca3d(prncomp.pca)
```

`[1] 0.4933764 0.3238404 0.3194022`

The above is all I get. I guess pca3d relies on RGL. I saw this other thread [Why is my 3D plot not showing up in R Studio plot viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212925/why-is-my-3d-plot-not-showing-up-in-r-studio-plot-viewer) bu was not able to solve my problem yet. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I am working on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: all I get is
 `> rgl::rglwidget()`
`Error in subsceneInfo(id) : No subscene info available.`
`Error in useSubscene3d(saveSubscene) : Subscene 0 not found.`

Comment: I uploaded the input binary matrix as a tsv: https://seafile.rlp.net/f/174caecec50344c7b822/?dl=1 @user2554330

Comment: sorry, did non know about the `dput()` function. The `dput(prncomp.pca)` file is too big to copy paste here, so U uploaded it again: https://seafile.rlp.net/f/cfcf7d433929459a8470/?dl=1